# Bypass visibility modifiers in Java

Tags: java

I need to access private and protected methods of 3rd party lib. I cannot use reflections due to performance requirements. Maybe there are any compiler settings allowing me to do this?

Comment: There is a reason why they are private.

Comment: If you need protected things, you could cheat by inheriting from their class. If you need private things and you can't use reflection or modify their code then I think you're out of luck. But before investigating either of those things I'd measure the performance of using reflection before dismissing it.

Comment: You can rewrite the bytecode (e.g with asm) to change the visibility on these methods/fields. What factor of "too slow" are you talking about, reflection is actually quite fast.

Comment: Have you actually checked how much slower the access with reflection gets? Is it really a problem, or do you just think so because a lot of people say "reflection is slow"?

Comment: Speed is really an issue, even a factor of 1.5 or so.

Comment: @user4276305 But have you *measured* the performance impact of reflection? The extra cost of reflection may be minuscule compared to the work done by the method being called. Beware [premature optimization](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/202153): Don't *assume* you have a problem unless you can see (measure) that you have a problem.

Comment: If there is no other option I will use reflection. I was only wondering if there is a better way...

Comment: Also remember that the biggest performance issue with reflection is likely obtaining the `Method` object, not calling `invoke()`. If performance it that critical, it likely means that you're doing the call often, e.g. in a tight loop, and you should then only obtain the `Method` object once and cache it.

Comment: @Bill your strategy of "cheat by inheriting from their class" doesn't necessarily work for protected stuff.  The conditions on `protected` are quite tight - if you inherit from a class in a different package, you can't run protected code in a different object.  This kind of makes it impossible to cheat, unless you can get the third party library to instantiate objects of _your_ class.

Comment: is the code to your 3rd party lib open? if so you could obtain it, modify it, and recompile. this is allot easier than it sounds if your project uses maven or gradle and the lib is hosted on github (add a line for jitpack).

Comment: @DavidWallace True, but I can just add the class to the same named package as it's not sealed. Very cheaty! (and highly not recommended).

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to modify the modifier of your methods then re-generate the bytecode using a library that allows to manipulate the bytecode such as [**Javassist**](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/) then patch your 3rd party library to replace the old classes with the new generated classes.

So for example, in the class `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` there is a method of type `private static long sizeOf0(File file)`, let's say that I want to make it `public`.

With Javassist you would proceed as next to generate your new `FileUtils.class`:

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
// Get the class org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils which is the class that 
// contains the method to modify
CtClass fileUtilsClass = pool.get("org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils");
// Get the class java.io.File which is the type of the parameter
CtClass fileClass = pool.get("java.io.File");
// Get the method to which we want to change the modifier
CtMethod method = fileUtilsClass.getDeclaredMethod(
    "sizeOf0", new CtClass[]{fileClass}
);
// Set the modifier of the method to public
method.setModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC);
// Write the new FileUtils.class in the user home directory 
// following the package name
fileUtilsClass.writeFile(".");
```

From here, you can simply replace the old `FileUtils.class` directly into the jar and rename the jar to indicate that it is not the original path but a patched jar file. So for example, here I could rename `commons-io-2.5.jar` into something like `commons-io-2.5-patch-01.jar`.